# Socket Timeout not working Python

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I'm noob with python and lora, I want to open a socket wait for a message, if there is no message then do something else, my code so far is:

```
import struct
import sys
import time
from socket import *
n = 0
try:
    the_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    exit('Error creating socket.')

while True:
    try:
        the_sock.settimeout(2)
        n+=1
        print("Hola"+str(n))
    except timeout:
        print("tiempo")
        break
```

Everything is working except for the timeout, I've checked some answers but the code looks good to me, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

`socket.settimeout` sets the timeout for blocking socket operations, such as `socket.recv`. You seem to have forgotten to include in your code a blocking action that can time out. Try adding a call to `sock.recv` inside your `try` statement.